# ContactListComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: No component factory found for ContactComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, typescript

I' m using try for make a `Dialog` in angular. by using `nebular`. I want to open `contact` component when click the button where is `contact-list` component. But there is a this fort of error.

```
ContactListComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: No component factory found for ContactComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

What should I have to do for this .

**contact-list.component.html**

```
<nb-card>
    <nb-card-header>
        THE HEADER
    </nb-card-header>

    <nb-card-body>
        <button nbButton (click)="addContact()">Add</button>
    </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

**contact-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { ContactService } from '../contact/contact.service';
import { ContactComponent } from '../contact/contact.component';
import { NbDialogService } from '@nebular/theme';

@Component({
selector: 'ngx-contact-list',
template: '<button nbButton (click)="open()">Open Dialog</button>',
styles: [
    `
    /deep/ nb-layout-column {
        height: 80vw;
    }
    `
]
})
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {
    isPopupOpened = true;

    constructor(private dialogService: NbDialogService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    open() {
        this.dialogService.open(ContactComponent, {});
    }
}
```

**contact-list.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ContactListComponent } from './contact-list.component';

import { NbCardModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { ContactModule } from '../contact/contact.module';

@NgModule({
declarations: [ContactListComponent],
imports: [
    ContactModule,
    NbCardModule,
    CommonModule,

]
})
export class ContactListModule {}
```

**contact.component.html**

```
Hello! this is the contact dialog
```

**contact.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'ngx-contact',
templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

**contact.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [ContactComponent],
imports: [CommonModule],
exports: [ContactComponent]
})
export class ContactModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

just as the error says, add it to your entryComponents :

```
// contact.module.ts
entryComponents: [
        ContactComponent,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ContactComponent to entryComponents:

#### contact.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [ContactComponent],
imports: [CommonModule],
exports: [ContactComponent],
entryComponents: [ContactComponent]
})
export class ContactModule {}
```